# Jquery mouseover do not work properly

Tags: jquery, mouseover

I have been write a jquery code  for slide to previous or next image in  element when hover the first or last

image but it not work properly, it just slide one time but not smoothly at first mouseover and after that it not slide any more when i mouseover again on it. please take a look and find out what happen in my code, why dont it slide smoothly ? and why do it slide when i mouseover again ?  thanks in advance .

You can look at the fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/9M3dM/

HTML code :

```
<div id="slide-wrapper">        
    <ul class="slide-container">      
        <li class="first">                
            <img alt="img slide movie" src="Images1.png" />
        </li>            
        <li>                
            <img alt="img slide movie" src="Images2.png" />
        </li>            
        <li>                
            <img alt="img slide movie" src="Images3.png" />
        </li>            
        <li>                
            <img alt="img slide movie" src="Images9.png" />
        </li>            
        <li>                
            <img alt="img slide movie" src="Images8.png" />
        </li>            
        <li>                
            <img alt="img slide movie" src="Images7.png" />
        </li>            
        <li class="last">                
            <img alt="img slide movie" src="Images6.png" />
        </li>            
        <li>                
            <img alt="img slide movie" src="Images5.png" />
        </li>            
        <li>                
            <img alt="img slide movie" src="Images4.png" />
        </li>            
        <li>                
            <img alt="img slide movie" src="Images3.png" />
        </li>            
        <li>                
            <img alt="img slide movie" src="Images2.png" />
        </li>            
        <li>                
            <img alt="img slide movie" src="Images1.png" />
        </li>        
    </ul>    
</div>
```

CSS code :

```
#slide-wrapper{
    position:relative;
    overflow:hidden;
    height:183px;
    padding-top: 1px;
}
#slide-wrapper ul.slide-container{
    overflow:hidden;
    position:absolute;
    width:100%;
    height:183px;
}
ul.slide-container li{
    cursor: pointer;
    display: block;
    float: left;
    height: 183px;
    padding-right: 1px;
    width: 145px;
}
ul.slide-container li img{
    border: none;
    height: 183px;
    width: 145px;
}
ul.slide-container li.last{
    padding-right: 0;
}
```

Jquery code :

```
(function ($) {
    var isAnimating = false;
    var methods = {
        init: function (options) {
            var self = this;
        },
        display: function () {
            methods.slide();
        },
        slide: function () {
            $(".slide-container li.last").mouseover(function () {
                methods._next(".slide-container", -147);
            });
            $(".slide-container li.first").mouseover(function () {
                methods._prev(".slide-container", 147);
            });
        },
        _next: function (target, move) {
            var base = parseInt($(target).css("margin-left"), 10);
            var maxLeng = ($("ul.slide-container li").length * $("ul.slide-container li").not("first").innerWidth()) - (7 * $("ul.slide-container li").not("first").innerWidth());
            if (base == maxLeng || isAnimating) {
                return false;
            }
            isAnimating = true;
            base = base + move;
            $(target).find("li.last").next("li").addClass("last");
            $("#slide-wrapper").animate({
                "margin-left": base
            }, 600, "easeInOutSine", function () {
                isAnimating = false;
                $(target).find("li.last:first").removeClass("last");
            $(target).find("li.first").removeClass("first").next("li").addClass("first");
            });
        },
        _prev: function (target, move) {
            var base = parseInt($(target).css("margin-left"), 10);
            if (isAnimating || base === 0) {
                return false;
            }
            base = base + move;
            isAnimating = true;
            $(target).find("li.first").prev("li").addClass("first");
            $("#slide-wrapper").animate({
                "margin-left": base
                }, 600, "easeInOutSine", function () {
                    isAnimating = false;
                $(target).find("li.last").removeClass("last").prev("li").addClass("last");
                    $(target).find("li.first").removeClass("first");
            });
        }
    };
    $(document).ready(function () {
        self.display();
    });
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: please put line breaks in ur code blocks...

Comment: Here is a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/9M3dM/

Comment: yeah, i formatted it for you :P to format it use linebreaks and the code button '{}' in the editor

Answer (score 0):

I think you messed up your code when posting.

> **Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token )**

```
display: function() {}) methods.slide();
//--------------------^
```

http://jsfiddle.net/9TRnR/

Comment: i fixed that error but it have not worked anymore. I do not know why ?